# how to show the icon of appropriate size in Image?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have icons for different resolutions in the resource file:

```
user@host :~/MyApp$ ls  icons/default/
20x20  20x20@2  20x20@3  20x20@4  index.theme
user@host :~/MyApp$
```

Now, I want to show automatically the icon of the corresponding resolution. When using icons in a `Button`, I just have to set the `icon.name` to the name of the icon and that's it.

But I don't need the icon to be part of the button. I just want to show a plain icon, so I think this has to be done using `Image`. I also want the icon to be selected automatically depending on the current resolution of the device.

Tried this

```
    Image {
       icon.name: "home_icon"
    }
```

but I get an error `Cannot assign to non-existent property "icon"`

How do you show an icon made for corresponding device resolution automatically?

My directory structure for icons is this:

```
Directories=20x20,20x20@2,20x20@3,20x20@4

[20x20]
Size=20
Type=Fixed

[20x20@2]
Size=20
Scale=2
Type=Fixed

[20x20@3]
Size=20
Scale=3
Type=Fixed

[20x20@4]
Size=20
Scale=4
Type=Fixed

user@desk :~/MyApp$ ls -lR icons/default/
icons/default/:
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 nov  3 16:07 20x20
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 nov  3 16:07 20x20@2
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 nov  3 16:07 20x20@3
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 nov  3 16:06 20x20@4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  280 oct 31 14:34 index.theme

icons/default/20x20:
total 52
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 485 nov  3 08:52 accounticon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 483 nov  3 08:55 countryicon.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 123 oct 31 14:35 drawer.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 301 nov  3 16:02 emailicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 413 nov  3 08:58 home.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 146 nov  2 15:44 humberger.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 237 nov  3 09:03 ico.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 378 nov  3 16:07 lockicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 268 nov  3 16:06 mobileicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 339 nov  3 14:37 usericon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 485 nov  3 09:11 verifybond.png

icons/default/20x20@2:
total 52
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1053 nov  3 08:51 accounticon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1232 nov  3 08:55 countryicon.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  126 oct 31 14:35 drawer.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  507 nov  3 16:01 emailicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  758 nov  3 08:57 home.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  215 nov  2 15:43 humberger.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  456 nov  3 09:03 ico.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  570 nov  3 16:07 lockicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  352 nov  3 16:06 mobileicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  549 nov  3 14:37 usericon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1136 nov  3 09:11 verifybond.png

icons/default/20x20@3:
total 52
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1672 nov  3 08:51 accounticon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1787 nov  3 08:55 countryicon.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  130 oct 31 14:35 drawer.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  785 nov  3 16:01 emailicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1057 nov  3 08:57 home.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  355 nov  2 15:43 humberger.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  718 nov  3 09:03 ico.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  969 nov  3 16:07 lockicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  677 nov  3 16:06 mobileicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  864 nov  3 14:37 usericon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1790 nov  3 09:10 verifybond.png

icons/default/20x20@4:
total 52
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2292 nov  3 08:50 accounticon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2610 nov  3 08:55 countryicon.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  131 oct 31 14:35 drawer.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1080 nov  3 16:01 emailicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1322 nov  3 08:57 home.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  473 nov  2 15:42 humberger.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1054 nov  3 09:02 ico.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1217 nov  3 16:06 lockicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  744 nov  3 16:06 mobileicon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1164 nov  3 14:37 usericon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2565 nov  3 09:10 verifybond.png
user@desk :~/MyApp$
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're using a plain `Image`, the high DPI variants of that image must be in the same directory:

```
default/
    home_icon.png
    home_icon@2x.png
    home_icon@3x.png
    home_icon@4x.png
```

Then you just set the source to the "regular" variant and Qt will pick the correct size:

```
source: "icons/default/home_icon.png"
```

However, if you want the convenience of `Button`'s icon API without using `Button`, you'll have to wait until [`IconImage` is made public](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66829).

Alternatively, you could just remove the `background` (and tweak the `padding` if necessary), without having to change the structure of your icon directory:

```
Button {
    icon.name: "home_icon"
    background: null
    leftPadding: 0
    topPadding: 0
    rightPadding: 0
    bottomPadding: 0
}
```

To make it a bit neater, you could create `IconImage.qml` and move the `Button` code above into it (without the `icon.name` assignment), so that it can be reused like so:

```
IconImage {
    icon.name: "home_icon"
}
```

Note that the button is still clickable with this approach, and although nothing will happen as a result of it being clicked, it does mean that it will consume mouse events. You could disable the button (`enabled: false`) to prevent this.

Comment: the problem is, my directory structure is different. I have updated the question to show the directory of icons. So, I am afraid if I use `source` on `Image` it won't find the correct file name because the name of the file doesn't have `@` sign.

Comment: I think the only way to fix it is to set up symlinks  to the original icons with the name that contains `@` sign

Comment: Did you try the button approach I mentioned? Then you wouldn't need to change your directory structure.

Comment: See https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtMvvm/blob/master/src/imports/mvvmquick/TintIcon.qml for an example of how to improve the "button icon" to not be clickable without greying it out due to the disableing.